# Does there have to be a string value in my setText?

Tags: java, android-studio, division, settext

Im trying to make an app that converts the value that the user inputs into the editText. But when I run the program it shuts down and won't show the input the user inputted or the input divided by 2. I tried putting btCalculate.setText("Hi" + convert); and that displayed hi and the user input but when I get rid of the string and just have convert it shuts down. Can someone help me or make sense of what I'm trying to do?
Here is my code:

```
    btCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int convert = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

            if (btCopper1.isPressed());
            btCopper2.isPressed();{
                btCalculate.setText(convert);
            }
            if (btCopper1.isPressed());
            btSilver2.isPressed();
                btCalculate.setText(convert/2);
            }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: You have mistakes in your code. Fix the { and }  from if’s.

Comment: Do I have to delete all of the { } between the ifs?

Comment: Depends on what you want your code to do.

Comment: I just want for example the second if I want it to print out the result which would be the users input divided by 2

Answer (score 0):

Is a good practice to code as simple as possible. It will be easier to found and fix issues.

Exemple:

```
if(expression == true) {
// do this instructions
}
```

In your code, start fixing the {}, making it easier to understand:

```
if (btCopper1.isPressed()) {
 btCalculate.setText(convert);
}
```

Think about it, it seems the error is in your logic.

Comment: simpler still than `if (expression == true)` is `if (expression)`

Comment: Yes, but the purpose of my comment was to be as didactic as possible.

Comment: How would you do it so there is two buttons that need to be true?

Comment: if (btCopper1.isPressed() && btCooper2.isPressed()) {
 btCalculate.setText(convert);
}

Comment: However `if (expression == true)` is commonly accepted as being poor coding style, since the `== true` is redundant.

Comment: @TiagoLuz I have used that code but when I press the calculate button nothing happens?

Comment: I am not sure if it is poor for beginners. I am trying to help being as simple as possible. Think about it and be as simple as possible to really help people, and not to being more confusing.

Comment: btCalculate is a button ? Have you instantiated it ? Any error on console ?

Comment: BTW, you will never press two buttons at the same time, so, this condition will never be true ...

Comment: Yes the calculate is a button and is instantiated and no errors are coming up just not displaying the text for some reason @Tiago Luz

Comment: Check if you did the right reference to object: Button btCalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btCalculate);

Comment: @TiagoLuz to me it looks like it should be working I just don't understand why it isn't setting the text

Comment: I think it is something to do with the &&